# Select data from xml using mysql ExtractValue()

Tags: mysql, xml

I want to extract location id from give xml, and also want to put condition that extract it if location does exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>1006221342207</id>
<name>Hitesh Modha</name>
<email>hitesh.99@hotmail.com</email>
<location>
    <id>115440481803904</id>
    <name>Ahmedabad, India</name>
</location>
```

I have tried :

```
SET location = ExtractValue(xml, '//locations//id');    
SELECT ExtractValue(location, '//id');
```

but it is not working.
Please help

Comment: You can use SimpleXML class then insert your data in the database

Comment: Your XML is invalid, it is missing a document element.

Comment: @ThW: It's not invalid, ExtractValue expects an XML fragment, not a Document, so it's fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The SQL

```
SELECT
  ExtractValue('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>1006221342207</id>
<name>Hitesh Modha</name>
<email>hitesh.99@hotmail.com</email>
<location>
    <id>115440481803904</id>
    <name>Ahmedabad, India</name>
</location>', '//location//id');
```

returns only an empty result, because the path `//locations//id` is empty for the XML fragment you use.

You're more likely looking for `'/location/id'` for the xpath expression, as it will return the id `text()` value: `115440481803904`

Next mistake you do is that you think `ExtractValue` would return an XML fragment you can re-run `ExtractValue` on. That's just not the case (only if - which is not the case in your example - there would have been XML encoded as CDATA in the located `text()` node).

All the details are explained in detail here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue

If you can not work around these misconceptions, there is no further suggestion I can give you.